# Not able to send email overriding create method django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I got to know that we can override create method in order to send email but it's not working with my code.

views.py:

```py
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_class = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

      file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)

      if file_serializer.is_valid():
          file_serializer.save()
          return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(FileUploadView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        send_email()  # sending mail
        return response

def send_email(request):
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Title',
        (FileSerializer.Fullname, FileSerializer.Email, FileSerializer.Contact),
        'mymail@gmail.com',
        ['anothermail@gmail.com']
    )
    email.attach_file(FileSerializer.Upload)
    email.send()
```

Help me in figuring out what's the problem here

Edit:  `APIView` doesn't support create method, above code doesn't work
. I want to send the contents received from post method from rest API through a mail. Suggest me a proper method in order to do it with respect to above code.

Comment: perhaps, you wanted to override `create` method in your seiralizer. `APIView` does not have a `create` method.

Comment: @alamshafi2263 I need to save the data of post method to database and send the saved contents in a email, suggest me how to to this and saved data consists of form-data with a attached file. It would be very helpful, Its bothering me from long time.

Comment: Where the problem? any error message or anything? Where you get `EmailMessage` ? if it is not you custom class also add imports. and it's not good by adding function `send_email` inside views.py create file email_utils.py then just import this function. Maybe in future you will need it for another actions.  Not informative

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen I'm not receiving any error and email is not sent. may be the way i wrote the code is wrong as it's been written in the edit. Help me in figuring out. I added all the necessary imports.

Answer (score 2):

> `APIView` does not support `create`

You have got this part right. You want to send an email after the model object has been saved to database. Actually there are several ways to do that. You can do it from view, you can do it from your serializer, you can do it from your model, you can do it from a `post_save` signal hooked to your model. I am going to show you what was wrong with your code and then some of the other ways -

1. The corrections to be made in your code that, you could call the `send_email` function just after `file_serializer.save()` in your `FileUploadView.post`

```py
class FileUploadView(APIView):
   parser_class = (MultiPartParser,)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

     file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)

     if file_serializer.is_valid():
         file_serializer.save()
         send_email() #sending Email
         return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
     else:
         return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def send_email(request):
   email = EmailMessage(
       'Title',
       (FileSerializer.Fullname, FileSerializer.Email, FileSerializer.Contact),
       'mymail@gmail.com',
       ['anothermail@gmail.com']
   )
   email.attach_file(FileSerializer.Upload)
   email.send()
```

2. This process also calls the `send_email` function from view, but this view is a bit different. This view inherits from `generics.CreateAPIView`

```py
from rest_framework import generics

class FileUploadView(generics.CreateAPIView):
   serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer
   parser_class = [MultiParser, ]
   queryset = FileUploadModel.objects.all()

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       serializer.save()
       send_email()
```

3. You can call the `send_email` function from the `create` method of your seiralizer. You can override `serializer.create` method

```py
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUploadModel
        fields = ['your', 'model', 'fields']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super(FileUploadSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        send_email()
        return instance
```

4. Sending Email from your `FileUploadModel` model class. Here you override the `save` method of the model

```py
class FileUploadModel(models.Model):
   ...your model fields definition...

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.pk:  #assuming we want to send email only when object is created first time in database
           send_email()
       super(FileUploadModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

On catch about overriding `model.save` method is that, it will not be called when you're performing bulk operations. Also it will be called every time you save the model i.e. both create and update that's why we added the `pk` check. This logic will send email before the object is inserted in your database if you want to send email only when the object is completely saved in database then do the following way with signals

5. You can hook a `post_save` signal to your model. In this way you send an email only after the object is saved in database

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=FileUploadModel)
def file_upload_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    send_email()
```

Catch with using signals is that it will not be called when you do bulk operation.

I am assuming you're fairly new to the django enviornment. You should also have a look on [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to perform long running background tasks such as - sending emails.